# Automate Rewriting New versions of image files Into Sub Folders That Contain the same files

Tags: macos, terminal, automation, automator, copying

I have a directory full of folders with sizes like this

```
mainfolder/
   folder100x100/
         img.png
   folder100x100/
         img.png
   folder100x100/
         img.png
   folder200x100/
         img.png
   folder200x100/
         img.png
   newimage/
      100x100/
         img.png
      200x100/
         img.png
```

I want a script that lets me copy new.png to all folders containing a specified dimensions in their name.. like "Copy new.png to all folders with 100x100 (and overwrite the old ones)"

Then I want to repeat the same thing with the "y" img.png, for 200x100 etc.

How can I set this up in OSX automator? (or terminal if easier).

Comment: You need to explain that a bit better, because so far, it makes about zero sense.

Comment: Ah, sorry it's tricky to explain.. I have a mainFolder directory.. in it I have a series of folders with dimensions in their filename.. each folder has an image file in it called img.png. I also have a folder called newImage in mainFolder with a series of folders inside containing new versions of img.png that apply to each size. I want a script that will copy img.png from newImage/x/ or newImage/y/ to folder100x100/img.png overwriting each folder that matches 100x100.

Comment: so the script needs to take a file from a directory, search other directories and match the directory name to "contains 100x100" and then overwrite the file inside with the new img.png

Comment: hang on I'll edit the original post to make it a tiny bit more clear..